# Why does Spark frequently increase and remove executors?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a spark job, Recently, this job has been executed very slowly, mainly because of the frequent addition and removal of excutor.[image]

I think there are two problems that should be optimized. The first is to reduce the removal of this excutor, and to reduce the time to recreate the excutor after removal, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you in Kubernetes ?

Comment: Is your spark Job using Dynamic Allocation? You can check `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout` in case it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Resource Allocation would explain this. This appears to be enabled. This is workload dependent as well as how the related parameters are set.